# Checking if the input has finished

Tags: java

So I'm a Java-newbie and started some playing with files. Say I have some file "tes.t" containing data of a type known for me - assume they're int-double-int-double and so forth. I don't know the amount of such pairs inside, though - how can I make sure the input has finished? For my current knowledge, I thought of something like this:

```
try{
        DataInputStream reading = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("tes.t"));
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println(reading.readInt());
            System.out.println(reading.readDouble());
        }
        }catch(IOException xxx){}
}
```

However, this infinite loop here makes me somehow uncomfortable. I mean - I guess the IOException should catch on as soon as the input has finished but I'm not sure if that's a good way to go. Is there any better way to do this? Or rather - *what* is a better approach as I'm sure mine is bad :)

Comment: Try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html

Comment: Infinite loop will hang your program with 100% CPU usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your file has int-double pair, You can do that as following:

```
DataInputStream dis = null;
try {
    dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("tes.t"));
    int i = -1;
    // readInt() returns -1 if end of file...
    while ((i=dis.readInt()) != -1) {
        System.out.println(i);
        // since int is read, it must have double also..
        System.out.println(dis.readDouble());
    }

} catch (EOFException e) {
    // do nothing, EOF reached

} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle it

} finally {
    if (dis != null) {
        try {
            dis.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
             // handle it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, but one more question... What if -1 was used as a proper int in the input? Wouldn't it then mistakenly ignore the while-loop and do nothing while there's still some input to work on?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like following:

```
try{
  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("tes.t");
  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  String strLine;
  //Read File Line By Line
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  System.out.println (strLine);
  }
  //Close the input stream
  in.close();
  }catch (IOException e){//Catch exception if any
 System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
 }
```

Note: This code is untested.

Answer (score 1):

This is from javadoc:

> Throws: EOFException - if this input stream reaches the end before
>   reading four bytes.

It means that you can catch `EOFException` to be sure that EOF reached. You can also add some kind of application level marker that shows you that the file has been fully read.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
DataInputStream dis = null;
try {
    dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("tes.t"));
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(dis.readInt());
        System.out.println(dis.readDouble());
    }

} catch (EOFException e) {
    // do nothing, EOF reached

} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle it

} finally {
    if (dis != null) {
        try {
            dis.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle it
        }
    }
}
```